# Angular input value from parent to child component doesn't work

Tags: angular, input, components, parent-child

I am trying to do a simple `@Input` and Angular simply refuses to take the value. I have the parent component, and inside its template I have:

```
<app-summary-data-row>
    [test] = "'ttt'"
</app-summary-data-row>
```

In the child component I have:

```
@Input() test: string;
```

In the child template I have:
**{{ test }}**
the value 'ttt' is simply not displayed. What can be the problem here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was my minor bug, typo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax is wrong. Try like this:

```html
<app-summary-data-row  [test]="'ttt'">   
</app-summary-data-row>
```